# Connecting and sending data to remote device using MQTT

Tags: mqtt

I am currently exploring MQTT. I am using the mosquitto broker. Using mosquitto, is it possible to publish data to a remote PC which is not in the same network as my PC? If yes,how?

Comment: An MQTT broker is not publishing anything. Instead, your _remote PC_ needs to subscribe to one or more topics in order to receive data.

Comment: Google "pubsub" to learn about the principle. Then you use a publishing client to generate the data, and a subscribing client to consume it. What's in the middle (the "broker") is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The MQTT broker needs to be accessable to all the clients (publisher, subscribers or both) that want to connect.

That means it needs to either be:

1. Running on a machine with a publicly accessable IP address. This could be by running the broker on a machine in the cloud.
2. Running behind a router with the correct port forwarding rules in place. This is most likely if you are running the broker on a home network.

If you intended to expose your broker to the internet like this you really should ensure you enable authentication and probably enable TLS support.